# from dataframe get number of days between the first order of the item A and the previous order which can be the item A or different item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe including all orders during one year of all customers.
I would like to know the average number of days between 2 orders:
The second order need to be a specific item. I call it Item A. This item have to be the first time or the second time a customer ordered it.
The first order can be item A or any other item. the first order doesn't mean is the first time the customer ordered. it is just the previous order.

Below is an example of the intitial table. it shows in bold the rows I am interested in.
to get the difference of days I will need to find a way to get the data in bold.

I have tried different things like groupby().first() or nth() but none of them do exactly what I want.

| customer | date | item A | item B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cust 1 | 2020/03/01 | 0 | 1 |
| cust 2 | 2020/03/02 | 1 | 0 |
| **cust 3** | **2020/03/03** | **0** | **1** |
| **cust 3** | **2020/03/04** | **1** | **0** |
| cust 3 | 2020/03/05 | 1 | 0 |
| cust 4 | 2020/03/06 | 0 | 1 |
| cust 4 | 2020/03/07 | 0 | 1 |
| **cust 4** | **2020/03/08** | **0** | **1** |
| **cust 4** | **2020/03/09** | **1** | **0** |
| cust 4 | 2020/03/10 | 1 | 0 |
| cust 4 | 2020/03/11 | 1 | 0 |
| **cust 5** | **2020/03/14** | **1** | **0** |
| **cust 5** | **2020/03/15** | **1** | **0** |

*EDIT :

output table expected :

There is 3 customers, each one have a difference of 1 day, so the average will be (1+1+1)/3  = 1 day

| customer | date | item A | item B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **cust 3** | **2020/03/03** | **0** | **1** |
| **cust 3** | **2020/03/04** | **1** | **0** |
| **cust 4** | **2020/03/08** | **0** | **1** |
| **cust 4** | **2020/03/09** | **1** | **0** |
| **cust 5** | **2020/03/14** | **1** | **0** |
| **cust 5** | **2020/03/15** | **1** | **0** |

Comment: can you add the expected output shape, just a table with the customer and the date difference? do you want to keep the customer like cust1 that don`t have the requirements? if yes what value you want in the table?

Comment: Hi Ben, I have edited my question.
My question is more on how to get the output table above than the average.
If I can have this output table then I will be able to get the average

Comment: Can orders contain both items?

Comment: Yes that can be possible. item A is a specific item, item B can be any other item but not A. a customer can buy on the same order item A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's make sure the `date` is a `Timestamp` and are ordered for each customer:

```py
df = df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])).sort_values(['customer', 'date'])
```

Then, as far as I understand the desired logic, it is:

- the main order of consideration is, for each customer, the first order containing `'item A'` among all the customer's orders except the first,
- the time difference is between that order and the preceding one.

One way to express that logic is:

```py
gb = df.groupby('customer')
a = gb['item A'].cumsum()
n = gb.cumcount()
mask = ((a == 1) & (n > 0)) | ((a == 2) & (n == 1))
```

Then, you can select that "order of consideration" and its preceding one:

```py
out = df.loc[mask | mask.shift(-1)]
```

That gives the dataframe the OP would like to get:

```py
>>> out
   customer       date  item A  item B
2    cust 3 2020-03-03       0       1
3    cust 3 2020-03-04       1       0
7    cust 4 2020-03-08       0       1
8    cust 4 2020-03-09       1       0
12   cust 5 2020-03-13       0       0
13   cust 5 2020-03-14       1       0
```

Or, to obtain directly the mean time difference between two orders:

```py
avg_dt = df['date'].diff()[mask].mean()
# Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, I am sorry but this is not exactly what I expected. There is some condition before looking at the difference.
I am trying to get the output table showed above or something similar.

Comment: In which way is it different from what you expected?

Comment: If you look at my output table, if a customer purchased the item A 5 times in different momment, the only ones I am interested in are the 2 first orders.
if a custome buy the first time  and the second time the item B and then buy the item A  3 times  ( B,B,A,A,A) , then I am interested only by the order 2 and 3

Comment: see rewritten answer in light of the additional explanations.

Comment: Oh thank you very much.
Your first answer helped me to get the result in another way:

just after your :
```df.groupby('customer')['date'].diff()```
I added :
```df = df[(df['dt'] != NaT & df['item'] == 'item A')]
df = df.groupby('customer').first()```